# Is there a way to sync livedrive to dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

Does anyone know how to sync Livedrive with Dropbox?  Searching for a more permanent source of storage that other dropbox users can't delete. Our company has both Dropbox and Livedrive, but uploading to Livedrive is a headache - is there an easy way to set up a constant sync between the two?